# Why is the copy constructor called for the statement d1=d2+d3 in C++?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I'm a beginner in C++ and the resource I'm using says that the following statement **d3 = d1 + d2;** calls the following:

- The + operator
- The default constructor
- The copy constructor
- Destructor
- Assignment operator
- Destructor

I don't understand why the copy constructor is called when the result is being assigned to a previously declared variable and why 2 constructors are called.

Operators are as follows:

```
date& date::operator=(const date& other)
{
cout << "Date assignment op" << endl;
    if (this!=&other){
        day=other.day;
        month=other.month;
        year=other.year;
    }
    return *this;
}

date date::operator+(const date& other) const
{
    cout << "Date Operator + called" << endl;
    date temp;
    temp.day=day+other.day;
    temp.month=month+other.month;
    temp.year=year+other.year;
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Type d3; d3 = d1 + d2. Which is why I'm struggling to understand it.

Comment: what is there inside your `+` operator overloading function?could you pls publish?

Comment: The copy constructor is used to construct the (temporary) return value of `d1 + d2`.

Comment: @DanielTaylor: Welcome to SO. please include relevant code snippets, including the declarations of `operator=` and `operator+`.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the operators.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The expression `(d1 + d2)` yields a temporary object while returning from operator+ (`return temp`). The creation of the temporary from 'temp' is done through the copy constructor. This is then assigned to d3.

Comment: Note that with NRVO/RVO, you may not see the call to the copy constructor. Please read up on Copy elision (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581424/how-to-check-for-c-copy-ellision)

Comment: @DanielTaylor interesting, I would have expected *named value optimization* to elide the copy construction.

Comment: @DanielTaylor see [here](http://ideone.com/s4omHW#view_edit_box) for an example of RVO (albeit without the N) in action.

Comment: @juanchopanza: may be a case of Debug vs Release build.

Answer (score 2):

When it calculates d1+d2, the result is a temporary object. For assigning one object to another the copy constructor is being called.

Comment: The wording is confusing. For assigning one object to another, what is really called is the assignment operator.

Comment: In operator+ for `return temp;` a temporary object is being made, for that the copy constructor is being called. This happens before reaching to assigning operator. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `return`'ing an object by value will copy-construct a temporary object from the source object and then pass along that temporary to the caller.  In other words, the statement `d3 = d1 + d2;` is basically doing this:

```
date implicit_temp(operator+(d1, d2));
d3 = implicit_temp;
```

Which breaks up into the following logic under the hood:

```
// The + operator 
date temp; // The default constructor
temp.day = d1.day + d2.day;
temp.month = d1.month + d2.month;
temp.year = d1.year + d2.year;
// return temp;
date implicit_temp(temp); // The copy constructor
temp.~date(); // Destructor
// Assignment operator
d3.day = implicit_temp.day;
d3.month = implicit_temp.month;
d3.year = implicit_temp.year;
implicit_temp.~date(); // Destructor
```

It is the same order as the output you are seeing.

If the compiler supports RVO (Return Value Optimization), it would be able to optimize away the temporary `date` object created by the `return` statement, by passing `d3` has a hidden parameter so `return` can just assign the `temp` variable directly to `d3` via its `=` operator, making the code behavior as if it were written like this:

```
void date::operator+(const date& other, date& result) const
{
    date temp;
    temp.day=day+other.day;
    temp.month=month+other.month;
    temp.year=year+other.year;
    result = temp;
}
```

Which would break down to this logic under the hood:

```
// The + operator 
date temp; // The default constructor
temp.day = d1.day + d2.day;
temp.month = d1.month + d2.month;
temp.year = d1.year + d2.year;
// return temp; - Assignment operator
d3.day = temp.day;
d3.month = temp.month;
d3.year = temp.year;
temp.~date(); // Destructor
```

Answer (score 0):

copy constructor is called when:

```
A a=b,
when you return an object,
when you pass an object.
```

your `+` operator overloading function returns a temporary object.which will actually call a copy constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Don't rely on that

Technically, your `operator+` has a `temp` variable into its block that has to be passed outside it into a temporary object to be later given to your `operator=`.

In other word, what your `operator=` see as a parameter is not the `temp` inside `operator+`, but a copy of it, that have to live longer than the `+` block, to let `=` to take place.

Howvever, if either:

- `+` has just only one return statement (as it actually have)
- `+` has all the return statements returning always just a same object

The compiler can optimize the copy-on-return by merging the temp local variable with the temporary used in the assignment, and leave out the copy at all.

This is one of very few optimization that can happen also cutting away side effects (see §12.8.15 of C++03 or 12.8.31 of C++11).

The fact the copy constructor is called or not, ultimately, depends on the compiler an on the level of optimization required.

(thanks to [juanchopanza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/661519/juanchopanza) for all the clarifications).

Comment: Copy elision can occur even if copy c-tor has side effects, no? Or is that allowed only in RVO?

Comment: @jrok: Being an optimization, it happens only if the external effect remains the same. If the copy ctor has side-effects, eliding will also elide the side effects, and this will change the external behavior.

Comment: @jrok You are right, copy elision *is* allowed to happen even if it eliminates side effects. It is an optimization that *can* change external behaviour. That is one reason it is really essential to know about it. Concerning this point, the answer is incorrect. Concerning the single return statement point, that isn't completely correct either. It can work if all return statements return the same object.

Comment: @juanchopanza: If -just for completness- you can specify the point of the standard that says it can be done even eliminating side effects I'll fix the answer.   (Or better: I can delete this if you post the correct one. Right now this is the only palace that talks about copy elision in the page, so it cannot be eliminated)

Comment: I think it was in §12.8 in the C++03 standard. I don't have access to a copy right now, but I can check later.

Comment: I just found [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890528/copy-constructor-elision).

Comment: Also 12.8.31 of C++11. Ok: enough info.